# Something implicit in directional derivative derivation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

While I was deriving the formula for the directional derivative, I came upon a step which seems somewhat weird. I just want to note, I have no problem with the concept and I realize that in a specified direction, the coordinates are no longer independent and so we can express a function of 2 variables by just one variable as long as we are on the line, and so we get a single variable function and differentiate to obtain the directional derivative. But I'm using the more general assumption that in *any* direction, the change can be approximated using the total differential.

While I was deriving the formula for the directional derivative, I came upon a step which seems somewhat weird. I just want to note, I have no problem with the concept and I realize that in a specified direction, the coordinates are no longer independent and so we can express a function of 2 variables by just one variable as long as we are on the line, and so we get a single variable function and differentiate to obtain the directional derivative. But I'm using the more general assumption that in *any* direction, the change can be approximated using the total differential.

So consider an arbitrary direction *S*;

$ \Delta Q_{1\Rightarrow2} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial X} \Delta X_{1\Rightarrow2} +  \frac{\partial Q}{\partial Y} \Delta Y_{1\Rightarrow2} $

& on the line S (S is a coordinate on this line), X & Y are not independent, and if the line is known, the angle $ \theta $ is known.

Thus,

$ \Delta X_{1\Rightarrow2} = \Delta S_{1\Rightarrow2}  \cos \theta $ & $ \Delta Y_{1\Rightarrow2} = \Delta S_{1\Rightarrow2}  \sin \theta $

Therefore,

$\frac{\Delta Q_{1\Rightarrow2}}{\Delta S_{1\Rightarrow2}} = \frac{\frac{\partial Q}{\partial X} \Delta X_{1\Rightarrow2} +  \frac{\partial Q}{\partial Y} \Delta Y_{1\Rightarrow2}} {\Delta S_{1\Rightarrow2}} = \frac{ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial X} \Delta S_{1\Rightarrow2} \cos \theta + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial Y}
\Delta S_{1\Rightarrow2} \sin \theta}{\Delta S_{1\Rightarrow2}}$

So, now, the $ \frac{\Delta Q_{1\Rightarrow2}}{\Delta S_{1\Rightarrow2}} $ becomes "instantaneous" that is;  $ \frac{\Delta Q_{1\Rightarrow2}}{\Delta S_{1\Rightarrow2}} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial X} \cos \theta + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial Y} \sin \theta = \frac{dQ}{dS} $

So, at the final step, it seems like we didn't *approximate* or take a limit to obtain an instantaneous ratio, it just "came out". I think it has something to do with cos and sin theta being ratios, or the property that if $\Delta X = \Delta S  \cos \theta $ then that implies that $X = S  \cos \theta$ ( that the change/delta becomes "instantaneous"). But I just can't seem to figure it out correctly.

Comment: you might get more help on your post if you incorporate the handwriting as mathjax directly within the post. [here's a mathjax tutorial :)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: It took me a lot of time and editing but I finally did it! (using phone) thanks though xD :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain what you're taking Q to be, but I think your confusion is coming from missing limits. $\frac{\Delta Q_{1\Rightarrow2}}{\Delta S_{1\Rightarrow2}}$ is a derivative, if you just take the limit: $\lim \limits_{\Delta S_{1\Rightarrow2} \to 0} \frac{\Delta Q_{1\Rightarrow2}}{\Delta S_{1\Rightarrow2}}$. Keep this notation throughout and it will start looking very much like definition of derivative problems you went through in calculus 1: the $\Delta S_{1\Rightarrow2}$ which approaches 0 will cancel out and you're left with an expression independent of that term completely, allowing you to calculate a real result.

Comment: Q is anything, Q= f(x,y)

Comment: It's just not like those other situations you describe, if you could give me an example to illustrate your point that would be nice

Comment: Check out the very first example from [this site](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/defdersoldirectory/DefDerSol.html). It is similar in structure to what I am describing.

Comment: My point is that it seems, *even* if $\Delta S$ *did not* approach zero, it seems that it will cancel out anyway and we'll get the same *instantaneous* expression.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it, maybe I thought about *too* much, because I know about such examples like the one you linked to..

Comment: As $\Delta S$ approaches a very small quantity, the ratio will aproach this instantaneous result. It makes sense now, thanks :)

Comment: Just as it would in the example given in the link above. We're talking about calculus here though. It doesn't make much sense to think about it approaching any other value in this context.